# Mac Address Error in Console Constantly Repeating AFter Connecting to School Network

Tags: wireless

I am continually getting this repeated error message whenever I connect to my schools network, via a WiFi connection. If I find a way to hard wire in I do not receive this error message.

This is what I found in my system log that repeats continuously. It's slightly distracting because it appears anywhere I type in my console, even when writing in an editor like vi or nano:

```
Nov 15 09:40:43 programming_box kernel: [ 2420.002726] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
Nov 15 09:40:49 programming_box kernel: [ 2426.007388] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
Nov 15 09:40:49 programming_box kernel: [ 2426.007459] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
Nov 15 09:40:55 programming_box kernel: [ 2431.967762] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address
```

Is there any reason for this or possibly a way I can get rid of it?

Comment: Please tell us more about your wireless device: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: lspci -nn -d 14e4 gave me an error of an "-d invalid device ID"
I tried just lspci and found "Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)". The rest are just PCI bridges and USB controllers. I'm fairly new to seeing this kind of stuff so I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try the native driver and firmware for your device. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: Completed. No errors detected in the system log after several reboots, thank you. Just to learn - why did this work?

Comment: This works because the STA driver wl is incorrect for your device. Please click 'accept' for my answer.